# Can anyone assist with a Type Error issue while using .map() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would anyone be able to help me with this error? I am trying to create a drop down picker for country names, pulling from the following API path: https://api.covid19api.com/countries

```
TypeError: Country.map is not a function
at fetchCountries (index.js:29)
at async fetchAPI (CountryPicker.jsx:13)
```

Here are the two code sections I am working in:

CountryPicker.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

import styles from './CountryPicker.module.css';

import { fetchCountries } from '../../api';

const CountryPicker = () => {
  const [fetchedCountries, setFetchedCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setFetchedCountries(await fetchCountries());
    };

    fetchAPI();
  }, [setFetchedCountries]);
  console.log(fetchedCountries);


  return (
    <FormControl className={styles.formControl}>
      <NativeSelect >
        <option value="">Global</option>
      </NativeSelect>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default CountryPicker;
```

index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const summary = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
const countriesURL = 'https://api.covid19api.com/countries';

export const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const { data: { Global: { NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered, }, Date } } = await axios.get(summary);



        return {  NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered, Date };

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }
}

//TODO
//Fetch Daily Data for charts using axios

export const fetchCountries = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: [ {Country} ] } = await axios.get(countriesURL);



     return Country.map((Country) => Country);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

    }
  };
```

I tried to look up why the error may be happening and I found that .map() will not work on a variable that is not an array, but I'm unsure with the current implementation, how to fix this

The data from the API looks like this:

```
[
    {"Country":"Micronesia, Federated States of","Slug":"micronesia","ISO2":"FM"},
    {"Country":"Bangladesh","Slug":"bangladesh","ISO2":"BD"},
    {"Country":"Bouvet Island","Slug":"bouvet-island","ISO2":"BV"},
    // ...and so on...
]
```

Comment: What does `await axios.get(countriesURL);` return?

Comment: The massive array of objects containing Country name, a slug of the country name, and one other unused value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restructure is not properly handled here.

```
const { data: [ x ] } = {data: [{"Country":"Micronesia, Federated States of","Slug":"micronesia","ISO2":"FM"},{"Country":"Bangladesh","Slug":"bangladesh","ISO2":"BD"}]}
```

Here `x` will be `{"Country":"Micronesia, Federated States of","Slug":"micronesia","ISO2":"FM"}`

**Next:**

`const {Country} = x`

Here Country will be `"Micronesia, Federated States of"`

and `"Micronesia, Federated States of"` is a string and it does not have `map` function.

So`{ data: [ {Country} ] }` is wrong way to access all keys.

```
const fetchCountries = async () => {
  try {
    const countries = await axios
      .get(countriesURL)
      .then((x) => x.data);
    return countries.map(({ Country }) => Country);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return []
  }
};
```

```js
const fetchCountries = async () => {
  try {
    const countries = await axios
      .get("https://api.covid19api.com/countries")
      .then((x) => x.data);
    return countries.map(({ Country }) => Country).sort();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return []
  }
};
fetchCountries().then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

**Fetch other info:**

```js
// const axios = require("axios"); // for node js

const fetchCountriesInfoParallel = async (countries = []) => {
  const promises = countries.map((country) =>
    axios
      .get(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${country}`)
      .then(({ data }) => data)
  );
  try {
    return await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return [];
  }
};
fetchCountriesInfoParallel(["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"]).then(
  console.log
);

const fetchCountriesInfoSeries = async (countries = []) => {
  let results = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < countries.length; index++) {
    const country = countries[index];
    const data = await axios
      .get(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${country}`)
      .then(({ data }) => data);
    results.push(data);
  }
  return results;
};
fetchCountriesInfoSeries(["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"]).then(
  console.log
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked perfectly! Is there a simple way to order the array alphabetically? Possibly lodash?

Comment: .sort() you can use. Updated check running version

Comment: I have another function that will fetch the live country data. It is structured similarly to the fetchCountries JSON response. If I wanted to get some fields besides the Country name, would I just simply add those props to the right side of the map() arrow function?

Comment: This is the route: https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${country}

Comment: Add ur expected output.

Comment: I have updated answer, u can check. You can merge calls

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the result of calling the API, it's in this form:

```
[
    {"Country":"Micronesia, Federated States of","Slug":"micronesia","ISO2":"FM"},
    {"Country":"Bangladesh","Slug":"bangladesh","ISO2":"BD"},
    {"Country":"Bouvet Island","Slug":"bouvet-island","ISO2":"BV"},
    // ...and so on...
]
```

So `Country` isn't an array, it's a property of each object in the array.

If your goal is to extract the `Country` property from each object, take the array and then use `map` extracting that property, perhaps with destructuring:

```
const data = await axios.get(countriesURL);
return data.map(({Country}) => Country);
```